# JMeter Parameterized Plug-in doesn't work under Loop controller

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I've noticed that JMeter Parameterized Plug-in doesn't work under Loop 
controller. It picks 1st value from CSV again and again..

Can someone help me with the steps?

Please find the attached Snapshot for CSV Data Set Config[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxba9.jpg)

Please find the attached snapshot for CSV Data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QANUD.jpg)

Scenerio: User LogsIn and picks value from csv(1st row) and does a search, then picks second row value and search again(Loop) and logs off. i.e i need to do multiple iteration of search for single user

Answer (score 0):

Change scope of your "CSV Data Set Config" to loop or Sampler instead of "Thread Group" or "Test Plan".

Means

Case 1: Won't work

[Does not work, if the scope of "CSV Data Set Config" to "Thread Group", as shown below]

```
Thread Group
    |
     ---Loop
    |
    |
     ---CSV Data Set Config
```

[image]
Case 2: Should work

"CSV Data Set Config" Scope should be to "Loop controller" or "Sampler", as shown below

```
Thread Group
        |
         ---Loop
             |
              ------CSV Data Set Config
        |
        |
```

[image]